# Web scraping: Servlet

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to download a zip file from a website (JS), for now I use selenium to do that I did the following ugly python script:

```py
base_url = "https://agreste.agriculture.gouv.fr/agreste-web/disaron/SAANR_DEVELOPPE_2/detail/"
driver.get(base_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div/article/div/div[1]/div").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a").click()
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result but without having to emulate the web browser with selenium?

I try to find an underlying server, but it seems that the link generate a JS servlet, which I do not know much about.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, it's possible. With REST or SOUP API. It seems to me that your question should be much more focused.

Comment: You mean SOAP? I am not sure that there is an underlying API behind, or I do not know how to access it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. I guess it should be. Also your `xpath`s here are terrible...

Comment: if you have access to that web server, you can download from there also ? maybe FTP ?

Comment: I just have access to the public website : https://agreste.agriculture.gouv.fr/agreste-web/disaron/SAANR_DEVELOPPE_2/detail/
I did not succeed to find any clue of a ftp or REST/SOAP Api